# What is the best way to add buttons in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

So I'm new to Xamarin Forms and I've found two ways of adding buttons:

1.Declaring the button in the .xaml file

```
 <!--  <Button Text="Click Me!"
      Clicked="OnButtonClicked" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />-->
```

and the .xaml.cs file

```
 public void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
     {
         count++;

         label.Text =
             String.Format("{0} click{1}!", count, count == 1 ? "" : "s");
```

2. declaring the button only in the .xaml.cs file

   ```
   using System;
   using Xamarin.Forms;

   namespace FormsGallery
   {
       class ButtonDemoPage : ContentPage
       {
           Label label;
           int clickTotal = 0;

           public ButtonDemoPage()
           {
               Label header = new Label
               {
                   Text = "Button",
                   Font = Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize(50),
                   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
               };

               Button button = new Button
               {
                   Text = "Click Me!",
                   Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large),
                   BorderWidth = 1,
                   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                   VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
               };
               button.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;

               label = new Label
               {
                   Text = "0 button clicks",
                   Font = Font.SystemFontOfSize(NamedSize.Large),
                   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                   VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
               };

               // Accomodate iPhone status bar.
               this.Padding = new Thickness(10, Device.OnPlatform(20, 0, 0), 10, 5);

               // Build the page.
               this.Content = new StackLayout
               {
                   Children = 
                   {
                       header,
                       button,
                       label
                   }
               };
           }

           void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               clickTotal += 1;
               label.Text = String.Format("{0} button click{1}",
                                       clickTotal, clickTotal == 1 ? "" : "s");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

but the thing is: I want to know which way is better for adding a button and to not have any future code problems.

Thank you!

Comment: There's no such thing as better when talking about code vs XAML it's just matter of preference, some like XAML while others prefer code.

Comment: someone posted same question xamarin forums have you looked at that..https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33175/which-is-the-best-way-to-design-the-ui-in-xamarin-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent.  Building your UI in XAML generally allows for a cleaner separation of concerns in your design, but one approach is not "better" than the other.

Answer (score 6):

Actually they are same. It depends on one's choice.

I prefer XAML over Code because

- XAML is cleaner and easy to understand.
- XAML seems to be able to better respect the "separation of concerns" between UI and controller logic.
- It has intellisense in Visual Studio

You can find your answer here in details
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter07/

Answer (score 0):

They are same. After building your UI with XAML, it's converted to their equivalent with C#, doing the same thing as writing with C# the view.

Code your UI as you like. For me the better approach is XAML as its more clean and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above comments that using XAML or C# depends on your preferences. Additionally I would recommend to study bindings and MVVM quite quickly because they make the UI code much cleaner. In the case of buttons you can use commands to directly refer to ViewModel instead of having Click listener in your UI code.

Here is a place where you can get started with data bindings and MVVM: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/